# How to aggregate character values in R data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame such as

```
df1 <- data.frame(
         A = c("USA","USA","UK","UK","France"),
         B = c("Boston","New York","Cambridge","Oxford","Paris")
)
```

And I would like to end up with a new data frame:

```
df2 <- data.frame(
         A = c("USA","UK","France"),
         B = c("Boston; New York","Cambridge; Oxford","Paris")
)
```

How do I aggregate by A using `paste()` as the "summarizing" function, or something equivalent to this?  Thanks in advance for any help provided.

Comment: thanks @DavidArenburg. despite my best efforts, i didn't find the question to which you linked and which of course gave me what i needed.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `data.table` for this:

```
library(data.table)
##
R> (df2 <- data.table(df1)[
  ,.(B = paste0(B, collapse = "; ")),
  by = "A"])
#        A                 B
#1:    USA  Boston; New York
#2:     UK Cambridge; Oxford
#3: France             Paris
```

And if you insist on having a `data.frame` for your result, just use `setDF(df2)` after.